# Trouble in creating database on android using sqlopenhelper

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have to create tables using sqlopenhelper. When I'm running the app in the emulator, the code is not giving error, but a log message from table creation is being shown. When I try to register the app stops.

I've used the following code:

```
package com.example.catchthebus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DbHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static String DB="CatchTheBus";


    public static final String Table_name="Driver";
    public static final String Driver_ID="Driver_ID";
    public static final String Driver_Name="Driver_Name";
    public static final String Driver_Contact ="Driver_Contact";
    public static final String Route_Num ="Route_Num";


    public static final String Table_Create="create table" +Table_name+"("+Driver_ID +"integer PRIMARY KEY,"+Driver_Name+" varchar(25),"+Driver_Contact +"integer,"+Route_Num +"integer"+");";


    public static final String LOGTAG = null;   




    public DbHelp(Context context) {
        super(context, DB, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try
        {
        db.execSQL(Table_Create);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

public void addDriver(String name ,String contact,String Route_num) {

        db.execSQL("insert into Drivers values(null, '"+name+"' ,"+contact+" , "+ Route_num+" )");
        String tag = null;
        Log.i(tag, "inserted value");


    }
}





main activity code:

package com.example.catchthebus;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //SqlHelp sql_helper;
    //SqlHelp sql_helper1;
    //SqlHelp sql2;

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelp;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbhelp = new DbHelp(this);
        database= dbhelp.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;


    }

    public void Open_Passenger_Submit(View view)
    {
        Intent intt=new Intent(this,Submit_Passenger.class);
        startActivity(intt);

        //sql_helper.createPassenger();
    }
    public void Open_Driver_Submit(View view)
    {`enter code here`
        Intent intt=new Intent(this,Submit_Driver.class);
        startActivity(intt);
        //sql_helper.createDriver();


    }
}
```

Comment: please post logcat exception.

Comment: when you print out Table_Create it looks like this:
create tableDriver(Driver_IDinteger PRIMARY KEY,Driver_Name varchar(25),Driver_Contactinteger,Route_Numinteger);

add spaces

Comment: Your CREATE TABLE statement needs **spaces** between objects, object names and object datatypes. Actually your table is **not** being created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Table_Create string was missing some spaces.

public static final String Table_Create="create table " +Table_name+" ("+Driver_ID +" integer PRIMARY KEY,"+Driver_Name+" TEXT,"+Driver_Contact +" integer,"+Route_Num +" integer);";

Comment: i tried using this code and still my table is not being created. –  
when i try to insert data in the table the app close

Comment: Don't forget, when you make a change, increment the database version.